# Using dash/hyphen in Razor Page filename - does compile but VS shows errors

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

There seems to be an issue with the Razor Pages (2.1.0-preview1-007211) and IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2017 (15.4.0 preview 2.0) with the filenames containing dashes.

In order to reproduce:

- Create a new razor page e.g. razorpagetest.cshtml
- In the code add

  ```
  @{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Test123";
  }
  ```
- Save and close the file
- Rename `razorpagetest.cshtml` to `razor-pagetest.cshtml`
- Save and close the file
- Reopen the file and you will see errors on the errors list (although it builds OK)

Has anyone experienced this issues? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Did you rename the code-behind page to razor-pagetest.cshtml.cs as well?

Comment: The code-behind gets renamed automatically so yes.

Comment: It looks like a parent folder containing dashes is also an issue.