# Add Razor Page' Dialog does not allow hyphens in a filename

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

From the references below, it seems that there has been an ongoing problem with hyphens in the filenames for Razor Pages.  The bugs below have been documented as fixed, but Add Razor Page still does not permit hyphens, as shown below:
[image: Error message]

My SEO guy insists that filenames must have hyphens, and if I rename a file later to put a hyphen in, it seems to work fine.

Am I correct in thinking this is a bug? Where should I report it?

References:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6296

[RazorPages with filenames that include a hyphen cause IntelliSense to break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854860/razorpages-with-filenames-that-include-a-hyphen-cause-intellisense-to-break)

[Using dash/hyphen in Razor Page filename - does compile but VS shows errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319581/using-dash-hyphen-in-razor-page-filename-does-compile-but-vs-shows-errors)

Comment: If renaming it later works fine, then yes it sounds like a bug.

Comment: I don't get that error. But the generated page ends up with an underscore instead of the hyphen.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue in Visual Studio 2017. Not sure if it's fixed in 2019 or not. I have to just remove the dashes and then rename the file afterward.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than try to battle with a bug or whatever it is, you could use an underscore where the hyphen should go and then use an `IPageRouteModelConvention` implementation to replace the underscore with a hyphen for routing purposes, keeping your SEO guy happy.

A suitable implementation might look like this:

```
public class HyphenPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
        {
            selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.Replace("_","-");

        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to register that at Startup:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new HyphenPageRouteModelConvention());
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);
```

You can read more about this interface here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/custom-route-conventions

Comment: OK. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the @page directive to explicitly give the route name.

```
@page "/multi-named/edit-me"
@model EditMeModel
@{
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it just doesnt work in ASP.NET 6

Comment: I am currently upgrading my .net core to 6.0 and I'll post any new solution I am required create.

Comment: I'm also looking for the way to fix this in .net 6.

Comment: So what I had to do was have the model name as shown above and not have an underscore. At first I had the file name and model of `Advisory_Board` which did not work. Once I changed to `AdvisoryBoard` and used the same code as above it worked.

Comment: It worked actually, I tested to post url directly on browser and it worked.
I was wrong when i was trying to use tag helper asp-page="/Page-Name" path. Later I changed it with adding full stock in start like asp-page="./Page-Name" and it worked.